# I want to delete a binary tree search but i get an error

Tags: c, binary-tree, address-sanitizer

I would like to delete a BST, my program works but, I don't know way, AddressSanitizer find an error.

```
void clear_maxlist(max_list* position){
  if(position == NULL)
    return;
  clear_maxlist(((position)->left));
  clear_maxlist(((position)->right));
  free(position);
}
```

I get this error:

```
==6643==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x0000004039c1 bp 0x7ffdc2a35f20 sp 0x7ffdc2a35f10 T0)
```

Comment: This question needs a [mre]. There cannot be anything wrong within the very excerpt that you presented as such, provided that the tree itself is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You must have one node in your tree whose `left` or `right` pointer should be `NULL`, but it is not. So, there must be an error in the code that constructs the tree.

Comment: It is very stange because the software works in all of the test that i tried.

Comment: Could be the 64bit processor a problem?

Comment: @Bob Rob - It is possible, that depends on the C code.

Comment: Ok, i find the solution, i didn't initialize a pointer to NULL.

Comment: @Bob Rob - I guess it is the AddressSanitizer that points out everything that _could_ cause a problem.